# Two selects, If you choose an option in one, some options in other are disabled

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

I'm working on a website with a "size" select and a "color" select.

to give an example

```
<select type="text" class="item_color item-dropdown">
 <option>blue</option>
 <option>red</option>
 <option>green</option>
</select>

<select type="text" class="item_size item-dropdown">
 <option>small</option>
 <option>medium</option>
 <option>large</option>
</select>
```

I would  like it so that, for example, if option red is selected, size medium and large are disabled ect.

Comment: Is JavaScript acceptable?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: one way is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zn2cb/1/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zn2cb/3/

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be

```
<select type="text" class="item_color item-dropdown">
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>green</option>
</select>
<select type="text" class="item_size item-dropdown"></select>
```

then

```
var map = {
    blue: ['small', 'medium'],
    red: ['small'],
    green: ['large', 'medium']
}

$('.item_color').change(function () {
    var sizes = map[this.value];
    $('.item_size').html(function () {
        return $.map(sizes, function (val) {
            return '<option>' + val + '</option>';
        })
    });
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zn2cb/)

Comment: Also, if I'm doing more than one items with different color size combos, could that be done with classes or IDs?

Comment: @CraigMacNeil sorry... I didn't get you... can you edit the fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: So item one has blue in medium and large, but say item two only has blue in small. I'm not savy in jquery so I dont know how to differentiate your "map" that says which colors carry which size. Also there are 75+ items to account for with many colors.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zn2cb/9/ ive added what im looking for into the css, thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, one question! I cant seem to add more than 6 Items to the jquery map, if i add 7 the sizes dont show up

Comment: @CraigMacNeil can you edit the fiddle to recreate your problem